# PHP Extract Codes From TextArea and Pass to Mysql SELECT IN Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following data which gets submitted in a text area:

```
new myProduct('', 'bbc_609'),
new myProduct('', '35857'),
```

What I am aiming to do is extract the codes from the above and pass just the codes to a Mysql Select IN query.

I can successfully get the codes out no problem with the following:

```
$text = trim($_POST['newfeatured']);
$textAr = explode("\n", $text);
$textAr = array_filter($textAr, 'trim'); // remove any extra \r characters left behind


foreach ($textAr as $line) {
  $g = preg_match("/new myProduct\('', '(.*?)'\)/i", $line, $match);
  $br = $match[1];
  echo "<br>";              
} 
// returns bbc_6093
// returns 5857
```

However, if I try:

```
var_dump($br)
```

... following is returned:

```
string(7) "bbc_609"
```

Or if I try to implode and echo, I get nothing back:

```
$gr = implode(", ", $br);
echo $gr;
//nothing returns
```

Therefore, given the above, I will not be able to pass the variable to the Mysql statement:

```
select product.productid, product.name, product.brand, price.code from product inner join price on product.productid=price.productid 
WHERE product.productid IN('".implode("','",$br)."')"; 
//if I pass in $br in this case.
```

I have also tried without the foreach loop:

```
if(isset($_POST['newfeatured'])) {
$g = preg_match_all("/new featuredProduct\('', '(.*?)'\)/i",$_POST['newfeatured'], $match); 
    $g = $match[1];

    $codes = implode(", ", $g); //so now we need to be able to pass $codes to the Mysql correctly.
    //var_dump($codes); returns the data in the array fine.
}
```

And when I try to pass $codes to the mysql select IN query, no data is returned?

Any help appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Using implode on a _string value_ (which your var_dump clearly showed you is what you have here) makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Use `preg_match_all` (and do away with the loop), or at least add the single matches you find inside your loop into an array - so that you _have_ something to implode afterwards.

Comment: So I need to put $br into it's own array?

Comment: If you want to have something that you can implode into a comma-separated string later ... yes.

Comment: Cool, cheers. I'll give that a go.  Thanks for your help

Comment: I have tried your suggestions and updated my question with more info CBroe but the Mysql query is still not working??  I can now see the data with var_dump() and print_r().  Hope you can help.

Comment: Well then make debug outputs, and check if $codes and your actual query look like you expect them to.

Comment: Bingo Cbroe.  At Last!!!  My implode formatting was fine, but when I echoed the $sql statement, the codes were not enclosed in single commas.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction helping me out.  Very much appreciated Cbroe :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First about the pattern:

- You don't need any capture groups just use `\K` to restart the fullstring match.
- I'd use `'[^']*'` on the first/empty single quoted component of your input string just in case some text does fill that position.

About your query:

- It is unsafe.  You must not directly insert user submitted data into a query for security purposes.
- Here prepared statements with `?` placeholders are used.
- Because the number of placeholders/params-to-be-bound are variable, the convolution of `call_user_func_array()` is required.
- I have also implemented `bind_result()` to aid in the processing of the resultset.

Untested Code:

```
$_POST['newfeatured']="new myProduct('', 'bbc_609'),
new myProduct('', '35857'),";

if(preg_match_all("/new (?:my|featured)Product\('[^']*', '\K[^']*/",$_POST['newfeatured'],$prd_ids)){
    $params=$prd_ids[0];  // the fullstring matches
    $count=count($params);  // number of fullstring matches
    $csph=implode(',',array_fill(0,$count,'?'));  // comma-separated placeholders

    $query="SELECT A.productid, A.name, A.brand, B.code
            FROM product A
            INNER JOIN price B ON A.productid=B.productid
            WHERE A.productid IN ($csph);";

    $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);  // for security reasons

    array_unshift($params,str_repeat('s',$count));  // prepend the type values string
    $ref=[];  // add references
    foreach($params as $i=>$v){
        $ref[$i]=&$params[$i];  // pass by reference as required/advised by the manual
    }
    call_user_func_array([$stmt,'bind_param'],$ref);    

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id,$name,$brand,$code);
    while($stmt->fetch()){
        echo "Whatever you want to do with the results: $id, $name, $brand, $code\n";
    }
    $stmt->close();
}else{
    echo "bonk";
}
```

Comment: mickmackusa, this is a much more elegant solution and definitely much safer.  It's really just a tool that I will use to search my local database for codes but I really appreciate the thought and effort you went into there.  I just had to update mysqli connection information and it worked just fine!! Big +1 from me.  Best regards.