# How to prepared statement for IN clause if there is mixed type array?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to write prepared statement for IN clause where array is mixed array. i am able to build array for 'call_user_func_array()' but i am not able to prepare statement. no output is showing.

this is my php code:

```
    $search1 = array('pune','india','2014','mumbai','2015'); 

    print_r($search1);

    echo $param = implode(",",$search1);

    $ids = array_flip(array_flip(explode(',', $param)));

    var_dump($ids);

    $type1 = array();

    foreach ($ids as $element) {

    if(is_string($element)) {
        $type1[] ='s';
    }elseif(is_int($element)) {
        $type1[] ='i';
        }
    }

    print_r($type1);

    echo $type=implode("",$type1);

    $inputArray[] = &$type;
    $j = count($ids);
    for($i=0;$i<$j;$i++){
    $inputArray[] = &$ids[$i];
    }

    print_r($inputArray);

    echo $clause = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($ids), '?'));

    $construct .="(city in ('.$clause.') or state in ('.$clause.')
          or country in ('.$clause.')) AND year in ('.$clause.') order by year desc";

    $constructs ="SELECT * FROM info WHERE $construct";

    if($stmt1 = mysqli_prepare($conn, $constructs)){

    call_user_func_array(array($stmt1,'bind_param'),$inputArray);

    if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1)){    

            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt1);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            echo $foundnum = mysqli_num_rows($result);
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

                echo $id = $row['id'];
                echo $name = $row['name'];

                }
            }
        }
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt1);
```

please tell me what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: Duplicates that I have answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48452420/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/47694473/2943403 I have been told that differentiating between `i` and `s` is not necessary when defaulting to `s` (I haven't tested that assertion).  *note that `is_int()` is checking the `type`, not checking if a string _may_ be interpreted as a numeric value.

Comment: When you `implode()` with an empty string as glue, you can omit that parameter from the call.  OOP (versus procedural syntax) is a less verbose style for processing mysql. I recommend that you capitalize `IN`, `OR` and `AND` in your query for improved readability.

Comment: Be aware that because you are using `$clause` four times in your query, you will need to generate 4x the number of binds so that there is a balance between placeholders and bound variables.

Comment: I find pdo is much better equipped for this kind of task.

Comment: I don't see any error checks in your code.  I recommend that you include those essential details when trying to debug your code.

Comment: Declare `count($ids)` to a variable so that you only call it once.  Declare `mysqli_num_rows($result)` to a variable so that you only call it once.

Comment: the input array is from checkbox so should i use prepared statement here?

Comment: This data is supplied from a user submission, so you should ABSOLUTELY use a prepared statement.  User-supplied data should always be considered "unsafe".

Comment: can you please tell me what should i change in above code? i am not finding any solution for this.

Comment: I am currently writing the code.  I don't like to post answers that I haven't tested first.  I don't put rubbish on StackOverflow.  I'll post as soon as it is ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**100% Tested and Successful Code**:

```
$search1 = ['2014','pune','india','2014','mumbai','2015','mumbai'];

// Separate logically and remove duplicates
foreach ($search1 as $value) {
    if (strlen($value)==4 && ctype_digit($value)) {  // qualifies for the year column
        $years[$value] = null;
    } else {
        $strings[$value] = null;
    }
}

$years = array_keys($years);  // move keys to values
$years_count = sizeof($years);

$strings = array_keys($strings);  // move keys to values
$strings_count = sizeof($strings);

if (!$years_count || !$strings_count) {  // this is a matter of program logic
    echo "A minimum of one year value and one non-year value is required for search functionality.";
}elseif (!$conn = new mysqli("host", "user","pass","db")) {
    echo "Database Connection Error: " , $conn->connect_error;  // don't show to the public
} else {
    $years_csph = implode(',', array_fill(0, $years_count, '?'));  // comma-separated placeholders
    $strings_csph = implode(',', array_fill(0, $strings_count, '?'));  // comma-separated placeholders

    $total_count = $strings_count * 3 + $years_count;
    $total_params = array_merge($strings, $strings, $strings, $years);
    $param_string = str_repeat('s', $strings_count * 3) . str_repeat('i', $years_count);  // write s chars before i chars

    if(!$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM info WHERE (city IN ($strings_csph) OR state IN ($strings_csph) OR country IN ($strings_csph)) AND year IN ($years_csph) ORDER BY year DESC")) {
        echo "Syntax Error @ prepare: " , $conn->error;  // don't show to public
    }else{
        array_unshift($total_params, $param_string);  // prepend the type values string
        $ref = [];  // add references
        foreach ($total_params as $i => $v) {
            $ref[$i] = &$total_params[$i];  // pass by reference as required/advised by the manual
        }
        call_user_func_array([$stmt, 'bind_param'], $ref);    

        if (!$stmt->execute()) {
            echo "Error @ bind_param/execute: " , $stmt->error;  // don't show to public
        } elseif (!$stmt->bind_result($id, $name)) {
            echo "Error @ bind_result: " , $stmt->error;  // don't show to public
        } else {
            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                echo "<div>$id : $name</div>"; 
            }
            $stmt->close();
        }
    }
}
```

Among other potential problems, `'.$clause.'` didn't look good because it was writing single quotes and dots around your placeholders.  Placeholder never need single quoting and that syntax would have been incorrect even if they did.

Comment: @vinay Dinner is served! ;)  ... of course you'll need to adjust this part: `"host", "user","pass","db"` to use your actual credentials.

Comment: thank you so much you saved my day. Dinner was very Dalicious. :). thanks again.